# JavaScript Leaflet - Adding custom icon images to Layer Control

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I've created several map overlays and the legend/layer control is automatically created for the buttons.  Ideally, I'd like to have my custom icon in place of the text "purple", etc.   Is there a way to do this?  I added comments with the image source file and the variable name for the icon.

```
//<img src="Images/purple.jpeg">  
//var purpleIcon = 'Images/purple.jpeg'

// Create an overlays object to add to the layer control
let overlayMaps = {
    "Up to $250K - purple": layers.one,
    "$250K - $500K- blue": layers.two,
    "$500K - $750K - green": layers.three,
    "$750K - $1M - yellow": layers.four,
    "Over $1M - red": layers.five,
    "School Quality": layers.six
};
```

[image: Layer control with current behaivor]

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/leafletjs/leafletjs_overlay.htm ... but you already do this a lot, so you must not even need to ask the question. Oh wait... there's no question?

Comment: @StackSlave - I'm learning JavaScript.  I don't know know how to add my icon to the quasi legend...please be kind. I'm asking for help.

Comment: https://codepen.io/haakseth/pen/KQbjdO ???

Comment: @StackSlave Thank you...doesn't quite do what I originally had wanted but did offer an alternative solution. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Control.Layers](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#control-layers) section of the [Leaflet Docs](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html):

> The baseLayers and overlays parameters are object literals with layer names as keys and Layer objects as values:

```js
{
    "<someName1>": layer1,
    "<someName2>": layer2
}
```

> The layer names can contain HTML, which allows you to add additional styling to the items:

```js
{"<img src='my-layer-icon' /> <span class='my-layer-item'>My Layer</span>": myLayer}
```

So, say you are using an Icon from Font-Awesome. You could set it up your control like so:

```js
L.control.layers(null, {
  '<i class="fas fa-bus"></i>': layer
}).addTo(map);
```

- [LIVE DEMO 1](https://plnkr.co/edit/Se17LxLjqGg6sJTYNCoq?p=preview)
- [LIVE DEMO 2](https://plnkr.co/edit/NCUhg9Hrkh1q5EC3wvWU?p=preview)

(Examples taken from [this answer on gis.stackexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/272633/icon-to-layer-control-leaflet-js))

Answer (score 3):

Thank you!  I ended up with this, and it works:):

```
let overlayMaps = {
                "<img src='Images/purple.jpeg' width = 15 /> <span>Up to $250K</span>": layers.one,
                "<img src='Images/blue.jpeg' width = 15 /> <span>$250K - $500K</span>": layers.two,
                "<img src='Images/green.jpeg' width = 15 /> <span>$500K - $750K</span>": layers.three,
                "<img src='Images/yellow.jpeg' width = 15 /> <span>$750K - $1M</span>": layers.four,
                "<img src='Images/pink.jpeg' width = 15 /> <span>$1M+</span>": layers.five,
                "School Quality": layers.six
            };
```